# Modify the TableRelation property in Business Central

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-business-central, dynamics-365-sales, businesscentral, dynamics-365-ce-onpremises

i'm trying to modify the TableRelation property of a standard field in BC, but without success.
Despite all my tentatives, seems that my modification is not perceived by Business Central.

Do you have any possible solutions to this problem?

I've tried to substitute the entire standard logic of the property, but without success.
I've tried to extend the property, adding some filters to the field using the TableExtension, but without success.

Comment: Please, provide AL code for the Field and TableRelation.
Question 1: Does the object (Table) compile without errors?
Question 2: Which version of BC are you using?

Comment: Which part of the code should i provide to you? I've tried to create something like this, but without success:

modify(FieldxStandard)
{
   TableRelation = Logic;
}

I'm using the 20.7 version of Business Central.

Comment: part of code like this one:
field(4; "Account No."; Code[20])
{
 Caption = 'Account No.';
 DataClassification = CustomerContent;
 TableRelation = if ("Account Type" = const("Bank Account")) "Bank Account" else
 if ("Account Type" = const(Customer)) Customer else
 if ("Account Type" = const(Vendor)) Vendor;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's not possible to extend the table fields TableRelation property without limitation. We have to add conditional based links like the following:

```
// Table field of table
field(3; Relation; Code[20])
{
  TableRelation =
    if (Type = const (Customer)) Customer
    else if (Type = const (Item)) Item;
}

// modify the table field via extension
modify(Relation)
{
    TableRelation = if (Type = const (Resource)) Resource;
}
```

> The combined table relation is evaluated top-down. That means that the
> first unconditional relation will prevail, meaning that you cannot
> change an existing TableRelation from Customer to Item, since the
> original table relation is unconditional.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/dev-itpro/developer/properties/devenv-tablerelation-property